# Python: Row-Based Mean for Subset of Columns

Tags: python, function, csv, web-applications, deploying

I am currently a beginning programmer working on a project to write and deploy a specific behavioral latency calculation online such that the app can accommodate any dataframe uploaded via CSV. The analysis requires that I take the mean of N number of columns within-person(i.e., within the same row) and iterate across all the respondents.

How can I take the specific instance where I perform this calculation, and turn it into a general function such that they apply more generally to any dataframe uploaded. For example, how can the row-based mean calculation below be written to work on N number of attributes/columns:

```
data['PersonalAverage'] = (data[[2]] + data[[4]] + data[[6]] + data[[8]] + data[[10]] + data[[12]] + data[[14]] + data[[16]] + data[[18]] + data[[20]] + data[[22]] + data[[24]] + data[[26]] + data[[28]] + data[[30]] + data[[32]] + data[[34]])/17
```

What if I uploaded a CSV with only 5 attributes (instead of 17).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Any reason for not using numpy? It comes with a mean function and functionality to select specific rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [data.mean](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) for such purpose.

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
1  4  5  6  7
2  2  4  6  8
3  3  2  1  4
4  0  1  2  4

In [4]: cols = ['a', 'b', 'd']    # Columns to consider for average

In [5]: df['mean'] = df[cols].mean(axis=1)

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
   a  b  c  d      mean
0  1  2  3  4  2.333333
1  4  5  6  7  5.333333
2  2  4  6  8  4.666667
3  3  2  1  4  3.000000
4  0  1  2  4  1.666667
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)
```

this should do the trick, however, if you have say an object type description in the first column you can skip that and calculate for the mean simply by using

```
df['mean'] = df.iloc[:,1:].mean(axis=1)
```